# What does 3-regularity mean in the context of this diagram of a fullerene?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, terminology

[This answer to *What is the maximum amount of carbon atoms that can comprise a fullerene?*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/158873/16035) links to [Mathematical aspects of fullerenes](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01416354/document) Vesna Andova, Frantisek Kardos and Riste Skrekovski Ars Mathematica Contemporanea 11, (2016) 353-379 (also [here](https://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/view/834)) begins

> Abstract
>
> Fullerene graphs are cubic, 3-connected, planar graphs with exactly 12 pentagonal faces, while all other faces are hexagons. Fullerene graphs are mathematical models of fullerene molecules, i.e., molecules comprised only by carbon atoms different than graphites and diamonds. We give a survey on fullerene graphs from our perspective, which could be also considered as an introduction to this topic. Different types of fullerene graphs are considered, their symmetries, and construction methods. We give an overview of some graph invariants that can possibly correlate with the fullerene molecule stability, such as: the bipartite edge frustration, the independence number, the saturation number, the number of perfect matchings, etc.

and later in Section 4.1 Cyclic connectivity:

> ...An example of a fullerene graph, in which the twelve pentagonal faces are partitioned into four clusters containing 1, 2, 4, and 5 pentagons each, is depicted on Figure 14. It is easy to see that this graph is not a nanotube.

I have annotated it and figured out how to get the twelve pentagons as four clusters containing 1, 2, 4, and 5 pentagons each by following the directions of making a second mirror copy, starting at one point and gluing them together.

The final result would be the second copy directly above (or below) the first.

**Question:** But what does "...such that the 3-regularity is preserved." mean? I'm not a a mathematician, and a term like "regular" can be used so many different ways in mathematics.

[image: Figure 14: A half of a fullerene graph, which is not a nanotube, but it is possible to separate six pentagonal face from the other six. In order to obtain the whole graph, the depicted graph is to be glued with its mirror copy along the boundary of the outer face such that the 3-regularity is preserved.]

> Figure 14: A half of a fullerene graph, which is not a nanotube, but it is possible to separate six pentagonal face from the other six. In order to obtain the whole graph, the depicted graph is to be glued with its mirror copy along the boundary of the outer face such that the 3-regularity is preserved.

Comment: I believe it means that every carbon atom is connected to exactly 3 neighbouring carbon atoms. More generally a graph is $n$-regular if every vertex is adjacent to exactly $n$ other vertices.

Comment: And a 3-regular graph is also often called cubic graph. I guess 3-regularity sounds better than "cubicity".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah! That explains the beginning of the abstract, *thanks!* "Fullerene graphs are cubic, 3-connected, planar graphs..." I couldn't figure out what "cubic" meant.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I think that nicely answers my question; if you are interested in posting it as a short answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph is called 3-regular if every vertex (carbon atom) has 3 edges (bonds). More generally, in an n-regular graph every vertex has degree n. Another name for a 3-regular graph is a cubic graph.

So 3-regularity is the property of being 3-regular, and I guess 3-regularity sounds better than "cubicity".